# haskell( Formulate and prove a base case and inductive step)

Tags: haskell

**I have some knowledge on haskell but need support to formulate and prove a base case and inductive step.**

The user-defined Haskell function

```
addtoall :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

defined below, adds to each entry of an integer list a specified number (the first argument ofaddtoall).

```
addtoall :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
addtoall n [] = [] -- a.0
addtoall n (x:xs) = (x + n) : (addtoall n xs) -- a.1
```

The following exemplifies the behaviour of
addtoall:

```
Exam> addtoall 3 [7,2,9,12]
[10,5,12,15]
```

Look at the interactive session shown here.

```
Exam>
addtoall 3 [7,2,9,12]
[10,5,12,15]

Exam>
addtoall 2 [10,5,12,15]
[12,7,14,17]

Exam>
addtoall 2 (addtoall 3 [7,2,9,12]
[12,7,14,17]
```

Based on this, it is suspected that for all finite lists xs of type
[Int] and all numbers m and n of type Int it is

```
addtoall m (addtoall n xs) = addtoall (m + n) xs
```

Prove this statement by Structural Induction on xs. It should be conducted in two steps

a) formulate and prove the base case
b) formulate and prove the inductive step

Comment: Have a go at least.  What do you know about how inductive proofs work? Give it a try, even if you're totally unsure.

Comment: ok i will post my attempt in a couple of hours but thankyou anywayz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as this is obvious some kind of homework I'll only show you the beginning.

So you should use structural induction - the only structure you have here is the structure of the list (and the exercise even tells you to ;)) - so the base case will be `[]` - what is the inductive case?

Now you have to prove it for both cases.

### how to do it

To prove this using *structural induction* on `xs` you have to prove two cases:

- the **base case** with `xs := []`
- the **inductive case** with `xs := y:ys`

In both cases the most simple thing to do is to work on the left and right hand side to see if both are finally equal (if you know how you can work on the left and change it into the right) - always using the function-definitions and the information you`ve got from the case at hand.

For example in the *inductive case*  you not only have that `xs = y:ys` but you may also use that

`addtoall m (addtoall n ys) = addtoall (m+n) ys` **(Ind)**

### base case

so start by simply writing both sides down and massage them with the definitions::

#### left:

```
addtoall m (addtoall n [])
{ a.0 }
= addtoall m []
{ a.0 }
= []
```

#### right:

```
addtoall (m+n) []
{ a.0 }
= []
```

obviously both sides are equal and you proved the first part.

Not think about the *inductive* case (hint: you surely need `a.1` and have to use induction somehow) and try it ... it should not be hard - you basically only have to rewrite the stuff you already have and then play *evaluator*

### inductive case

Please try it with this template:

#### left:

```
addtoall m (addtoall n (y:ys))
{ a.1 - inner }
= addtoall m ((y+n) : addtoall n ys)
{ a.1 - outer }
= ((y+n)+m) : addtoall m (addtoall n ys)
{ Ind }
= ((y+n)+m) : addtoall (m+n) ys
{ arithm }
= (y+(m+n)) : addtoall (m+n) ys
```

#### right:

```
addtoall (m+n) (y:ys)
{ a.1 }
(y+(m+n)) : addtoall (m+n) ys
```

**remember** in the end you should see the same thing

### remarks

- I think you tried the right thing there but you should really add the needed steps (but your solution looks like the thing you want to see both left and right - so work towards it)
- usually you write `x:xs` in the inductive case but I wanted to make sure that you try the steps - also I was afraid that you might missinterpret `xs:=x:xs` ;)

### external links

- [Structural induction - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction)

Comment: so here u have proved the base case using 'addtoall m (addtoall n xs) = addtoall (m + n) xs' and also line a.0 from the function addtoall? so i am guessing you have done the right hand statement and left hand statement.

Comment: I finished the *proof* as I think it' s ok now (after almost a week)